# Running Java Class under Linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, class, exception, terminal

I'm trying to run a JAVA Class under Linux Mint from the Terminal.

My Java class runs nice within any IDE, so I know it's not a code problem, but actually need to run it from the Command Line this time. However, I'm having issues at this point.

I used the following command:

```
java -cp . Interface
```

But it happens that it gives me an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Interface (wrong name: client/Interface)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I'm looking to understand all the components that could make it possible to solve this issue and to be able to overcome future problems on the topic.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what is the package name of `Interface` or its default?

Comment: Post your code (though it's likely the answer below hit the answer on the head)

Answer (score 4):

Your class resides within the package `client` so you have to change the current directory to the parent directory and run it with `java -cp . client.Interface`. `ls` should show you a directory named `client`.

```
<current directory>
└ client
  └ Interface.class
```

So using the information you gave in the comments to another answer, your current directory should be `NetBeansProjects/ServerClient/build/classes/` when starting the application using the above command line.

Answer (score 1):

Provide package name as well:

```
java  -cp . client.Interface
```

Run this command from the Project root (aka at the same place where is your `bin` file)